# signed char declaration in C

Tags: char, signed

I am confused with this

```
  signed char x=01234;

  printf("%d %d\n", x,~x);
```

Output is -100  99
I understand difference between x,~x (binary complement) but I am confused with char declaration like this. If i have ' ' signs then its represent characters, without ' ' should be ascii code but how to interpret  x=01234  like consecutive digits or whole number. Char is 1 byte long so maximum should be 255 or 128 with sign. How to explain the result -100 and 99.
Obviously I mixed up everything, sorry but i would appreciate some help....

Comment: The value 01234 (=668) can't be represented as a signed int, so is converted to a signed char in an implementation-defined way (an implementation-defined trap representation is also possible according to the standard). Here, the top bits are being cut off, and the remaining lower 8 bits are treated as a two's complement number.

Comment: I try to understand what u have writed but .... 01234 = 668  ?  top bits, remaining ? Could you please explaine it in details ?

Comment: It's explained in detail in the standard: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf . Assignment is section 6.5.16 and octal constants are in 6.4.4.1